# angular shadow DOM, child component trigger ngOnChanges twice

Tags: angular, shadow-dom

angular shadow DOM, child component trigger ngOnChanges twice, and first time all input data are undefined. How to avoid the first trigger?

## a.component, is Shadow DOM.

**ts:**

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output, SimpleChanges, ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-a',
  templateUrl: './a.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./a.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})
export class ContainerComponent implements OnInit {
  
  @Input() mode?: string;
  @Input() size?: string;
  @Input() fileList?: any;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

}
```

**html:**

```
<div #container>
  <app-b
    [mode]="mode"
    [size]="size"
    [fileList]="fileList">
  </app-b>
</div>
```

## b.component

**ts:**

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output, SimpleChanges, ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-b',
  templateUrl: './b.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./b.component.scss'],
})
export class ContainerComponent implements OnInit {
  
  @Input() mode?: string = 'edit';
  @Input() size?: string = 'm';
  @Input() fileList?: any = [];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes); 
  }

}
```

when I import a component named a, and use it like below, function of ngOnChanges will be trigger twice in b component. First time, get all input data are undefined, the second time get `{size: 'g'}`; at the time, `mode` and `fileList` are both change to `undefined`, not default value `'edit'` and `[]`.

```
<app-a size="g"></app-a>
```

I want to know how to avoid the first trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, ngOnChanges will be triggered before the B's (or any component's) onInit, and second time it will be called after B's onInit, i.e. when the binded data came from A. You cannot avoid the triggers - you can only choose wether you'll act upon changes or not. The fact that you can log changes doesn't mean you must act on them.

Second, the default value of an Input is not a "real" default value, I mean not in the sense in which you expect it to behave: it will have that initial value *only* if nothing is passed to Input i.e. if the value is *not* binded in parent component. However, your A component *does* bind values to B's Inputs, and the problem here is that the A itself is not getting those values passed to it. So when you only pass `size` to A, it will get passed to B, but other Inputs will be undefined because their values are binded in A's template, but they have no values (nothing passed to A for them). So B's onChanges will fire before B's onInit the value `undefined` for all Inputs, then B will get `size` from A (because A got it from its parent) and so B's `size` will be 'g'. However, nothing was passed to A for other Inputs and they stay undefined - so they're undefined in B too, since they are binded in A's template.

If you want to have 'real' default values, you can use setters and getters for Inputs or set the values in onInit.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer, can I ask another question? Because b is actually my lib component, but I need to wrap another layer and package it into a web component with Shadow DOM. I want to not record the first changes (undefined) in the web component. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you actually have a code in onChanges that is triggered on each change, or are you having some logic there only if some specific value changes? Also, if you use those inputs in template, you can always put `*ngIf="size"` etc. where you use them

Comment: Having some logic there only if some specific value changes. the issue is some input data not passed from A be changed to `undefined`, then I got them in B will be `undefined ` like `mode` and `fileList` in code.

Comment: Because all input data are not required. The user can choose to pass any or none of them.  So  I can't use either as a condition for `*ngIf`.